# CentOS 6: configure: error: the compiler must support C cleanup handling

Tags: linux, installation, centos, compile, glibc

I'm trying to install `glibc 2.14` on `CentOS 6 - centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.x86_64` from [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz)

while running `./configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14` command, I am getting following error

```
configure: error: the compiler must support C cleanup handling
```

complete configure output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/kr1Nkkmv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install DevToolset 3 GCC and GCC C++ Compiler

```
yum install devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
```

Download glibc-2.14 source

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz
```

Uncompress glibc-2.14

```
tar xfz glibc-2.14.tar.gz
```

Enable DevToolset-3 in new bash shell

```
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

Change to glibc-2.14 directory

```
cd glibc-2.14
```

Create build directory as you cannot configure the source dir and navigate there

```
mkdir build && cd build/
```

Run configure with the prefix option to specify directory in which glibc should be located

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14
```

Run make

```
make -j4
```

Before installing glibc require ld.so.conf file to be created in the destination directory. Create the file and directories

```
mkdir -p /opt/glibc-2.14/etc ; touch /opt/glibc-2.14/etc/ld.so.conf
```

Install GCC to destination directory

```
make install
```

Export GLIBC library path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib
```